# tree-toggle to be closed on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree

I don't know js but have to occasionally use it, so sorry if question is trivial but I try diffrent things and they don't work for me.

So I have a tree and I have this script that actually works and hides displays the tree branches when clicked.

However by default  the tree is open. How can I force the tree to be closed when it first loads?

```
     <!-- 

 - HIDE DISPLAY TREE BRANCH WHEN CLICKED ON HEAD ITEM -->
            <script>
                   $(document).ready(fu

nction () {
                    $('label.tree-toggler').click(function () {
                $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(300);
                    });
                  });
         </script>
```

this is my source html

```
                        <ul class="nav nav-list tree">




                                         <li><div>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                                           S: # 2  Men Fashion (<i> <a href="/item/subcategory/subcategory_details/2"> Details </a> - <a href="/item/itemgroup/new/2/http://127.0.0.1:8000/item/category/list/%3Fid=2&name=&keywords=&author=&creation_time=/">Add Itemgroup</a> -
                                          <a href="/item/subcategory/edit/2/http://127.0.0.1:8000/item/category/list/%3Fid=2&name=&keywords=&author=&creation_time=/">Edit</a> -
                                          <a href="/item/subcategory/delete/2/http://127.0.0.1:8000/item/category/list/%3Fid=2&name=&keywords=&author=&creation_time=/">Delete</a></i>)</div>
                                               <ul class="nav nav-list tree">




                                                             <li><div><i>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                                                               I: # 21  ffdsfdsf </i>(<i><a href="/item/itemgroup/itemgroup_details/21">Details </a>-
                                                              <a href="/item/itemgroup/edit/21/http://127.0.0.1:8000/item/category/list/%3Fid=2&name=&keywords=&author=&creation_time=/">Edit</a> -
                                                              <a href="/item/itemgroup/delete/21/http://127.0.0.1:8000/item/category/list/%3Fid=2&name=&keywords=&author=&creation_time=/">Delete</a></i>)</div>



                                                             </li>




                                                             <li><div><i>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                                                               I: # 22  saddascsa </i>(<i><a href="/item/itemgroup/itemgroup_details/22">Details </a>-
                                                              <a href="/item/itemgroup/edit/22/http://127.0.0.1:8000/item/category/list/%3Fid=2&name=&keywords=&author=&creation_time=/">Edit</a> -
                                                              <a href="/item/itemgroup/delete/22/http://127.0.0.1:8000/item/category/list/%3Fid=2&name=&keywords=&author=&creation_time=/">Delete</a></i>)</div>



                                                             </li>




                                                  </ul>



                                 </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either use css adding `display:none` to your ul

like `<ul class="nav nav-list tree" style="display:none">`

or call a jquery when the page is loaded `$(this).parent().children('ul.tree').css('display', 'none')`;

Answer (score 1):

Use `<ul class="nav nav-list tree" style="display:none;">`. Wat jquery toggle does, is set display to either none (hidden) or block (visible.)